# Prototypal Inheritance. Whats wrong with this simple example?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

```
    function a (){
        this.testing = 'testing';
    }

    function b (){

    }

    b.prototype = new a();



    console.log(b.testing);
```

The console shows undefined, rather than 'testing'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't made an instance of 'b' yet.

```
var bInstance = new b();
console.log(bInstance.testing);
```

In other words, the properties of the prototype only appear on objects of type `b`, not on the `b()` constructor function itself.

Comment: Thats exactly what it was. Thanks! SO is telling me I have to wait 9 mins to accept your answer. Will do it then.

Comment: I just noticed your variable sounds like "a newbie" when you say it outloud - maybe I need some sleep.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I think I'll edit the name so it doesn't sound like I'm being mean :D